# Swagger for spring not showing routes

Tags: spring, rest, swagger-2.0, springfox

Here is my configuration files:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {

    Docket result = new Docket(
               DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(
                                      RequestHandlerSelectors.any()).paths(
                                                       PathSelectors.any()).build();

    return result;
    }
```

}

And:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyWebMvcConfigurerAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry.addResourceHandler(
                "swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations(
                                    "classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

    registry.addResourceHandler(
                "/webjars/**").addResourceLocations(
                                "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

}
```

Here is a simple controller i have:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TestingController extends AbstractController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/play", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseDTO foo(@RequestBody RequestDTO requestDTO) throws IOException {

return this.myService.exec(requestDTO);
}
```

For some reason the url:

```
http://localhost:8080/app/v2/api-docs
```

Gives me the following:

```
{"swagger":"2.0","info":{"description":"Api Documentation","version":"1.0","title":"Api Documentation","termsOfService":"urn:tos","contact":{},"license":{"name":"Apache 2.0","url":"http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"}},"host":"localhost:8080","basePath":"/app"}
```

I have many many controllers and methods, why aren't they being displayed? 
P.S - The

```
Docket result = ...
```

seems to be returning no paths\routes, why?